# Unexpected value align parsing preserveAspectRatio attribute Firefox error

Tags: javascript, firefox, warnings

Does anyone have any idea what this warning/error means in firefox:

**Unexpected value align parsing preserveAspectRatio attribute.**

Comment: What is the URL of the page where you see that warning?  And, what do you have to do on that page to cause it?

Comment: Just made a fiddle to recreate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/unPrz/5/

Comment: I have no idea what it is.  The closest I can find to something like that is this SVG attribute:  http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute, but I don't know if that is what is in play here or not.

Comment: Only in Firefox too.  Don't see it in Chrome or IE - though Chrome has a different (built-in) flash player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like that there's a `preserveAspectRatio` attribute set on an element that isn't getting parsed correctly.

What are you trying to do in your JavaScript?

Comment: It happens when I click on links that .html() new iFrame content into a div.

Comment: Ok, not liking the fact that I can't post images since I'm a newbie, but you pretty much said it. It's an HTML5 attr issue inside of the YouTube iFrame. Had to dig deep, but eventually got it. Thanks for all your help! <svg class="annotation-close-button" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 16 16" preserveAspectRatio="align">

Comment: @spez86 No problem! :) I'm glad I could be of assistance to you today. I used to not be able to post pictures either... I hated it. You should now though, as you have 10 reputation :)

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be an issue with the youtube iframe embed method. I had the same issue and it's solved if you use the old embed method (HTML  tag).